# How to display message when a user submits the form

Tags: php

Hi I have the following code. I was just wondering how to add a message/popup to say "thanks for registering" if everything is successful. Here is the code and btw i am new the php. Thanks for your help

```
<?php 
require("config.php");
if(!empty($_POST)) 
{ 
    // Ensure that the user fills out fields 
    if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
    { die("Please enter a username."); } 
    if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
    { die("Please enter a password."); } 
    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    { die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); } 

    // Check if the username is already taken
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            username = :username 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( ':username' => $_POST['username'] ); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ die("This username is already in use"); } 
    $query = " 
        SELECT 
            1 
        FROM users 
        WHERE 
            email = :email 
    "; 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 
    try { 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
    if($row){ die("This email address is already registered"); } 

    // Add row to database 
    $query = " 
        INSERT INTO users ( 
            username, 
            password, 
            salt, 
            email 
        ) VALUES ( 
            :username, 
            :password, 
            :salt, 
            :email 
        ) 
    "; 


    // Security measures
    $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 
    $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 
    for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){ $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); } 
    $query_params = array( 
        ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
        ':password' => $password, 
        ':salt' => $salt, 
        ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
    ); 
    try {  
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    } 
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 
    header("Location: index.php"); 

    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 


}
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -- insert instead of the `header( Location:index.php);` and `die()` lines:

Following will display Thanks message for FIVE (`content=5)` seconds before redirecting to index.php

```
echo '<h1>Thanks for registering</h1>';
echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=index.php">';
```

Comment: IS it possible to add css to this message as it is plain at the moment. Other than that great answer

Comment: `<h1 style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">Thank you</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using jquery?
You can use the "$("#id").submit(function(event)){} with one alert, it will give you a popup with a personalized message.